# In jQuery, how do you make a mousedown() event trigger a resizeable box feature?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In jQuery, how do you make a mousedown() event trigger a resizeable box feature?  A similar idea is cropping.  You click on the picture and drag your mouse and it creates a box to the size of your choosing.

```
$("div").mousedown().resizeable();
```

or

```
$("div").mousedown(function(){ $("div").resizeable()}
```

Comment: Are you actually after image cropping, like this? http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/ or something similar for another purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want the [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) plugin?

Oops I just realized it the same link as the one Nick added as a comment - please give him credit if this is what you needed.

Edit: I found another crop plugin called [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/).